# How to check status of one port on remote host using NSClient++?

Tags: windows-server-2003, batch-file, nagios, nsclient++

I know I could check for telnet on a known IP using other programs like:

```
nmap -A 192.168.0.1/32 -p 23
```

Or, look for open ports from 20 to 30 on host.example.com:

```
nc -z host.example.com 20-30
```

I need to create a **batch** file, since I think that is how NSClient++ works on Windows Server being monitored by Nagios. Currently I have CPU, Disk, Memory, NSClient, and PING being monitored but I need a Specific **port** that I can also Monitor.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to check connectivity TO another host from the monitored Windows host, right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a monitored Windows server, and you want to check to see if it has connectivity to a remote machine, I would recommend the following:

Use [this PowerShell code](http://poshcode.org/3058) (or one much like it) to write a script that checks a remote port.

Then set up the [CheckExternalScripts](http://nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/CheckExternalScripts) module to run and interpret the output of the PowerShell script.